# Verilog: Re-assigning a variable in an always block

Tags: verilog

I want to create a logic where I update the value of a register whenever there is a pulse.
In this, I need to update the all the register bits (8) to 1 except for one variable bit (x in below snippet) which needs to be set to 0.

For this I have a simple logic in place but I am not sure if this is synthesizable. I have not run lint yet.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge resetn)
begin
  if (resetn == 1'b0) begin
    mask <= 8'b1;
  end
  else begin
    if (pulse) begin
      mask[7:0] <= 8'hFF;
      mask[x] <= 1'b0;
    end
    else
      mask[7:0] <= mask[7:0];
  end
end
```

Is this the best way to do it. I don't think so. Please suggest what should be the right way to do it.

Comment: what is `x` in mask[x]? Try to simulate first.

Comment: X is a variable as I have explained in the description.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make multiple assignments to the same variable (whole or a select of the variable) in the same `always` block. The last assignment *wins*.

Also, you should remove the  `mask[7:0] <= mask[7:0];` statement. It is unnecessary any sequential always block retains the value of any unassigned variable. This dummy assignment can interfere with a testbench's attempt to override the behavior for debugging or error injection.

Comment: This works also for <= assignments? I thought that this work only for = assignments.

Comment: It works for both when they are in the same procedural block. See the section on _Determinism_ in the LRM. Section 4.6 in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

Answer (score -1):

looks good,
as mentioned you can remove:

> else
> mask[7:0] <= mask[7:0];

you might consider also adding synchronized reset in a form of "kill" or something so you wouldn't have to use the a-synchronized reset "resetn"